# Does $watch not work for immediate statements?

Tags: angularjs, watch

skipping the same old ... I am new to bla bla...

I have this confusion, where in my code given below, when i change the value of my variable "watchVar" (which initially will have 10, but in a different view) in a way shown in the current code, does not trigger watch (I don't knw if it's an event). (I can confirm that by Log messages, no messages printed)

But when I toggle the comments for the statements 2 and 9, $watch works.

```
$scope.funcy = function(){          
        //$scope.watchVar=""; // Resetting So the watch on this variable calls a method     
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'myUrl',
            headers : {'Content-Type' : 'applicaiton/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function(response){
            if(response.response_code==1){      
                $scope.watchVar=""; // Resetting So the watch on this variable calls a method       
                $scope.mylist = response.results;
                $scope.watchVar= $scope.mylist[0]; //gives 10
            }               
        });
    }



$scope.$watch('watchVar',function(){
        console.log("watch watchVar : " + $scope.watchVar);     
        if(angular.isNumber($scope.watchVar)==true){
            // call a func
        }
    });
```

I could think of two reasons.

1. Immediate changes for same variable may not be caught by watch.
2. Final changes for a variable are not reflected in real time if the changes are made in a block or something, here in this case success method.

Does any of the above two statements give the reason for this behavior or is there any other reason that i obviously don't know.

Again same old.. thanx in advance etc etc. ;P

Edit :
I wrote a big paragraph trying to explain my scenario, and realized it would have been more pain in ummm eyes... yeah eyes.. than writing all that.
So deleted that.
I realized I have other ways and work around.

Was just curious to know why my one scenario worked and other didn't when both were doing the same thing.

Comment: Out of range question : why do you need to watch your variable in your case ? The promise resolution doesn't make the job in your case ?

Answer (score 0):

A watcher is called **in a digest loop** if the value of the watched expression has changed **since the last digest loop**.

If you do something like

```
var old = $scope.watchVar;
$scope.watchVar = "";
$scope.watchVar = old;
```

Then angular, when the digest loop is executed, still sees the same value for watchVar as in the previous digest loop.

What you're trying to achieve is unclear, but a watcher is probably not the right solution (it rarely is).

Comment: so does it mean the statements you wrote in above example are not going to be seen by watch? but when i put few statements in between the two assignments it works.

Comment: No. The number of statements you put between these is irrelevant. Here's how it goes: 1.digest loop. watchVar = "foo". 2. a whole lot of statements executed by your http callback. watchVar's value changes a million times, but at the end, it's set to "foo". 3. digest loop executes. watchVar has the same value as in 1: "foo". So your watcher is not called.

Comment: I'll try few snippets regarding it to get a clear picture like putting a block between the assignments and putting simple statements between the assignments. Will then be able to decide actually what watch is for. Your explanation will definitely help. Also I'll read about digest, (now that i know what and where to look for.)